# trying to understand the asynchronous call behaviour and main queue in swift

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, firebase, dispatch-async

I have an `Authenticator` class having `sendEmailForPasswordRecovery`  method implementing `asynchronous` call that sends the email to `firebase` user for password recovery.

```
func sendEmailForPasswordRecovery(email: String, completion: CallBackWithError) {
        FIRAuth.auth()?.sendPasswordResetWithEmail(email, completion: { (error: NSError?) in
            completion(error)
        })
    }
```

I am calling this `function` from a `UIViewController`

```
Authenticator().sendEmailForPasswordRecovery(email, completion: { (error: NSError?) in
      print("operation completed. error: \(error)")
      self.completion?()
})
```

The completion blocks simply calls this function. It simply **hides** a **popUp** view, and **fadeout** the **blurEffect** and **removes** it from its **parent view**.

```
func removeForgotPasswordScreen() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { 
            self.blurEffectView.alpha = 0
            self.containerForEmail.alpha = 0
        }) { (_: Bool) in
            self.containerForEmail.hidden = true
            self.blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
```

but when `Authenticator().sendEmailForPasswordRecovery` is executed I can see that the error is nil in console. But the **popUp** View is disappearing only after 40-50 second later. But when I wrap the completion inside `dispatch_async`, I get my result immidiately.

```
Authenticator().sendEmailForPasswordRecovery(email, completion: { (error: NSError?) in
   //   self.completion?() <----- this was causing delay

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
          self.completion?() <------ Now it updates immidiately
    })
})
```

Firebase `sendPasswordResetWithEmail` has signature:

```
public func sendPasswordResetWithEmail(email: String, completion: FIRSendPasswordResetCallback?)
```

and it says

> @param completion Optionally; a block which is invoked when the
>   request finishes. Invoked
>               asynchronously on the main thread in the future.

What I dont Understand is why did the PopUp was disappearing after certain delay in the first place and How did the `dispatch_assync` did the job immidiately.

Comment: a quick suggestion - I recommend reading about Grand Central Dispatch (GCD), which is the system for working with concurrency in iOS development.

Comment: When do you set the completion variable - are you sure it is set correctly in the first case? Add a breakpoint in the removeForgotPasswordScreen to see when that is actually called, and from what thread.

Comment: @MattLeFleur thanks for suggestion. that was extremely helpful.

Comment: For others, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrlUEUfbC1M  this video explains it pretty nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To animate the views, you should use main queue, and **sendPasswordResetWithEmail** not invoke your block in main queue, and it emphasized:*Invoked asynchronously on the main thread in the future.*

**dispatch_async** will enqueue execute block into the queue of thread, but this thread is not guaranteed to be main thread or has a low priority, such as **dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {}**, so I guess **sendPasswordResetWithEmail** implements its method use DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT or other low priority, that makes your code can't be guaranteed to execute immediately, in fact the execute's time is not accurately confirmed. Below is a test, the label's animation sometimes execute after many seconds, sometimes not execute.

**Notice**: handle or set UI must in main thread, this is just for test.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
let label = UILabel()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 21)
    self.label.text = "Label"
    self.label.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(self.label)

    let button = UIButton(type: .System)
    button.setTitle("Button", forState: .Normal)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.label.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.label.frame) + 20, 50, 20)
    button.addTarget(self, action: NSSelectorFromString("handleButtonPressed:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
}

func handleButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    // the block will execute not in main queue
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(1)
        // because the queue is not main queue, the animation not execute immediatelly, even not execute.
        UIView.animateWithDuration(3, animations: { 
            var origin = self.label.frame.origin
            origin.y += 100
            self.label.frame.origin = origin
            }, completion: { (complete) in
                self.label.hidden = true
        })
    }
}
}
```

But if you change to main queue, the animate will execute as your hope time.

```
func handleButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    // in main queue
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(1)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(3, animations: { 
            var origin = self.label.frame.origin
            origin.y += 100
            self.label.frame.origin = origin
            }, completion: { (complete) in
                self.label.hidden = true
        })
    }
}
```

So, you should execute all code that ralate to UI in main queue(main thread).

Hope the answer can help you. This is [GCD's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html), it explains carefully and completely.